# jQuery form .submit(); not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've seen a few posts already trying to submit a form with jquery in firefox but I can't get any of those solutions to work in my forms.

I have two forms on my page and what I'm trying to do is submit them both at the same time. I currently have the first button submitting form #2 and when form #2 is submitted then submit form #1. I have to have it this way because the place I am hosting these forms require a page redirect. I can't get both forms to submit if both are redirecting so I submit form #2, block the redirect, then submit form #1.

Both forms are submitting and posting data perfectly in Chrome and IE but I can't get the form labeled "form2" to post the data when using Firefox. Why is form1 posting the data but form2 is not posting the data when I'm using firefox?

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reazx3r1/1/)

```
/*  trigger second form submit when clicking first form submit */
// form 1 button submits form 2
$('#submitform1').click(function() {
  $('#form2').submit();
});

//on form 2 submit, stop the confirmation page and don't run a function on completion
$('#form2').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'url',
    data: $('#form2').serialize(),
    complete: function() {}
  });
});

//when form2 submits, submit form 1
$('#form2').submit(function() {
  $('#form1').submit();
});
```

Comment: Submit form1 when form2 submit is finished? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes when form2 has been submitted then form1 should submit. I tried accomplishing this in the ajax complete but it wasn't working so I had to pull it out of there and place it at the bottom as you can see

Comment: It should be in the ajax success, simple as that - if that didn't work you need to show your code because that is the right way to do this - unless you want to use promises, but I would try this first

Comment: I had already tried that and I wasn't able to submit either form: successs:function(){
  $('#form1').submit();
  }

Comment: Either form? What error did you see in the browser console?

Comment: It says it can't access the post action url but if I keep it the way I have it in the fiddle it submits just fine. But I still can't get it to submit in firefox which is the main issue i'm having

Comment: I added an update to the question. "form1" is submitting and posting data in firefox but I still can't get "form2" to post data. Is this an issue in my ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, we'll use promises:

```
/* create a function to submit the forms */
function formSubmit(el, url) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: url,
      data: el.serialize(),
      complete: function() {}
    });
}

/* now we say, when first form has been submitted, submit the next */
$.when(formSubmit($('#form2'), 'http://myAjaxUrl2/')).then(function() {
  formSubmit($('#form1'), 'http://myAjaxUrl1/')
});
```